# Windows Keeps Losing Wireless Printer - Needs To Be Re-Added Every Day

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, printer

I have a wireless network with a number of laptops and a Deskjet 2540 wireless printer. The laptops are running Windows 7 with one of them running Windows 8. The wireless modem is a Netgear.

If I, through Add Devices and Printers, add a new printer, Windows finds the printer on it's IP address and adds it correctly. A test print works, as well as normal printing. Actually, when doing the search for printers, the wireless printer pops up in the list very quickly within 2 or 3 seconds.

However, once I power down a laptop, the next time I boot it up the printer is marked as unavailable and I cannot print until I go through the Add Printer process again. Re-rebooting the laptop or restarting the printer has no effect. It seems the only way is to re-add the printer.

Is there a way to make sure the printer does not get forgotten? Or should I instead be looking at wiring up the printer to the network instead (which would require a USB to Ethernet adapter)? Would that make it more stable?

Comment: Does your printer go to sleep/standby when you notice the printer stops being identified by Windows? Does the printer no longer appear in Devices and Printers when the problem arises - or does it appear faded?

Comment: The printer does go to standby/sleep, but it wakes normally when a print is done except in the circumstances described above. I don't think it grays out in devices and printers, it just tells me it's unavailable in the properties view. (I'm not currently at that location so can't be sure.)

Comment: The deskjet at my office seems to be forgotten and one of the laptops scans for a new driver (usually failing) on bootup. The laptop is wireless running windows 8.1, the deskjet is wired directly to the network. Take that info for what you may get out of it. It is not mine but finding the correct driver when it refuses to print seems to work, though annoying to have to do that. I wonder if it is an HP driver issue...